# Time Calculation Issue: Mod function does not work as desired when seconds exceed 100

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am pretty new to excel and function writing. Currently I am trying to prepare a function which will let me divide 5 minutes into 10 seconds segments.

I looked around the internet and stackoverflow to find an answer to my issue. I found out  the function =TIME(0,TRUNC(B3/100),MOD(B3+10,100)) seems to work until the seconds value + the number I am adding (which is 10 in the example) exceeds 100.

[Please have a look at screen shot of excel sheet](http://prntscr.com/bw0zpp).

Cell B3 is direct input (no formula) and its format is 00:00. Starting from B4, the formula is almost same for all the cells in column. The only difference is that as it goes from B4 to B11 the "seconds" part of function which I add multiples of 10 changes as +10 for B4, + 20 for B5, + 30 for B6, etc. Currently B11 comes up as 29:08 instead of 30:48 and the formula for B11 is =TIME(0,TRUNC(B3/100),MOD(B3+80,100)).

I believe the problem is very basic and does not require much knowledge but even though I looked around I could not figure out the solution. As of now I am trying some if statements but no luck so far..

I would really appreciate it if you can help me out with this.

Comment: What is your expectation?

Comment: I want cell B11 give 30:48 as the result of formula and B12 to give 30:58 and B13 to give 31:08, etc. The general expectation is to automatically segment 5 minutes into 10 seconds parts when the user inputs data for cell B3

Comment: I would assume you want to divide/mod by 60 and not 100

Comment: mod by 60 doesnt work. At least in this formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is the most complicated way to achieve your aim.

I would suggest:

- Put `=TIME(0,29,28)` into cell B3
- Put `=B3+TIME(0, 0, 10)` into cell B4
- Copy the content of B4 to the cells B5 to B??
- Format all cells as "mm:ss"

Comment: Maybe the cell format should be `[mm]:ss` if the minutes shall go over 60. Otherwise after 59:58 will come 00:08.

Comment: Worked! I tried that kind of solution but when formatted to mm:ss I could not be able to input time in right format. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Minutes will not exceed, but thanks for the tip Axel!

Comment: @eserco: For direct input without `TIME` function, you must input it beginning with the hours : `0:29:28`. The first value before `:` is taken as hour always, then minutes, then seconds.

Comment: Thank you for your help Alex